Filter child data from parent (1-n relation)
I have created a PostgreSQL database that contains 9 tables. The structure is as follows: I have my "mandat" table, which is the parent of the "Batiment" and "Route" tables, which each have child tables, etc... In short, my "mandat" table is at the top of the pyramid.
In QGIS, I would like to filter my "mandat" table to display only one mandate and its children. So far, no problem using the filter function and the expression builder. The only issue is that only the data from my "mandat" table is filtered. The data from the child tables still contains all entities, including those referencing a different mandate than the one I want.
Is it possible to apply a filter to achieve the result I want?
(Without creating a filter on each table, obviously. This solution works but is absolutely impractical).
